# Need to count the occurrences of "Y" in the second position in a string in a rang

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Column A with char string, B has formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqNIe.png)

I have column A with a 4 character string that is 18 rows deep.  I want to count how many occurrences of "Y" are in the second position in the string for the range.  I have tried a bunch of combinations of countif and mid to no avail.  The strings look like this (in case the image is unclear)

```
1YN2
2NN2
0YY1
```

Comment: `=SUM(IF(MID(A1:A18;2;1)="Y";1;0))` as an array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

Comment: or, even simpler: `=COUNTIF(A1:A18;"?Y*")`   (search 'wildcard' here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A1:A18,2,1)="Y"))
```

[image]

Comment: Where is this feature documented (by Microsoft?) i only could find this [site](https://www.listendata.com/2012/10/why-two-minus-signs-in-excel-formula.html) with info on the meaning of the two minus signs `--(....)`

Comment: @Luuk  I do not know.

Answer (score 2):

The [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) supports wildcards:

`=COUNTIF(A1:A18;"?Y*")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `COUNTIF` function as you can see in the image

`?` means 1 character and `*` means any numbers of characters (including 0).

[image]